# What is the drawback if a model implements interfaces?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am new to EF Core. Some models of my web app will be displayed as list items of a dropdown control.

I create an interface and a model as follows.

```
public interface ISelectListItemable
{

    int Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Tag : ISelectListItemable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Therefore I can create

```
public static class IEnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItem<T>(this IEnumerable<ISelectListItemable> items, int selectedValue)

    {
        return from item in items
               select new SelectListItem
               {
                   Text = item.Name,
                   Value = item.Id.ToString(),
                   Selected = item.Id.Equals(selectedValue)
               };
    }
}
```

to easily obtain `SelectListItem` lists.

## Question

As far as I know, I don't see any tutorial with models implementing interfaces. So my question is there any drawbacks in my code above?

Comment: This question is too broad. Does the code work as is?

Comment: @mjwills: I have checked just for a single model with CRUD and it works. But I wonder  why there are so many tutorial with standalone class for the models.

Comment: When you create a tutorial, you generally want to teach **as little as possible** for your point to get across. Adding interfaces to the tutorial would add cognitive load, with marginal benefit. So it is left out.

Comment: @mjwills: By the way, I noticed that any data annotation attributes applied to the properties in the interfaces will not affect the generated schema. So the attributes must be explicitly specified in the class implementing the interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what (or: how much) architecture you are using.

The name `ISelectListItemable` suggests a UI concern.  I would consider this a viable addition for a ViewModel, not for a Model.

When you are using your Models directly in the Views then you might do this but it will reduce the scalability and flexibility of your design.

Basically it is in the same league as putting `[DisplayName()]` on your Model properties. Some people do that, but only in smaller projects.

Regarding the maping in EF Core,

> I noticed that any data annotation attributes applied to the properties in the interfaces will not affect the generated schema.

Correct, that is by design and the only way it could work.

It makes the interface less intrusive than a base class. EF probably never sees the interface. So when you do use something like this, it is much better than inheritance.

Comment: Actually I want the data annotation attributes in the interfaces to affect the generated schema even though the model class implementing them do not explicitly specify the data annotation attributes. Thereby I can strictly express my intent that the drop down list item cannot have null `Name`. 

Having read your extra explanation above, it means that I have to use an abstract base class instead of an interface.

Comment: "have to use an abstract base class" - maybe, but I would make that an bastract `SelectedItemViewModelBase` or something. Make sure you know about AutoMapper.

Comment: "cannot have null Name" is a legitimate constraint for a Model too, but not because of a dropdown list. Keep an eye on that distinction. You can always filter or add substitutes in the UI layer.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know about AutoMapper right now. I will learn it later.